# Does each irreducible polynomial over the integers represent at least one prime?

Tags: number-theory, polynomials

There's not much more to the question: If $f(x) \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial, is there a simple proof that there must be some $x$ for which $f(x)$ is a prime number (positive or negative, e.g. $f(x)=-13$ is OK here)?

By irreducible I mean to imply that $f(x)$ is not $0$ or a unit of $\mathbb{Z}[x],$ as some texts demand of an irreducible element. But to simplify things, just assume $f$ has degree at least $1$ [the degree 0 irreducibles being integer primes anyway, which do represent at least one prime].

UPDATE: Note that an example of Hurkyl's gives an irreducible $f$ not representing any primes. $f(x)=x^2+x+4.$ This was pointed out by Lucien in a comment, and that comment has a link to the question with Hurkyl's polynomial in an answer.

Comment: How about $f(x)\equiv 1$?

Comment: The statement is true for first degree polynomials.

Comment: @vladim Yes I thought about that odd case, but in one text I use for this it says that irreducible implies nonzero and nonunit. However for clarity maybe I should just put in "nonconstant" as a proviso.

Comment: How about $f(x)=2x$?

Comment: @barakmanos $f(1) = 2$ is prime then.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Yep, "my bad" as they often say around here. But what about $f(x)=4x$ then?

Comment: @barakmanos Not irreducible, $f(x) = 2\cdot (2x)$ - at which point I note that $f(x) = 2x = 2\cdot x$ is also not irreducible.

Comment: @Lucian Yes! The polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x^4$ given by Hurkyl in the linked question has all of its values greater than $2$ and also even, so gives a counterexample, since $p$ is irreducible: $p(t+1)=t^2+3t+6$ is Eisenstein at the prime $3.$

Comment: @Lucien oops I meant of course $x^2+x+4.$